# Creating shipment programatically issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, new-shipment

I am facing an issue with creating a shipment programatically. This is my code:

```
    // Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order
    $shipment = $this->convertOrder->toShipment($order);
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
        if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
            continue;
        }

        $shipmentItem = $this->convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($orderItem->getQtyToShip());
        $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
    }
    $shipment->register();
    try{
         //Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface
         $this->shipmentRepositoryInterface->save($shipment);
    }catch (Exception $exception) {
        $this->logger->error(sprintf($exception->getMessage()))
    }
```

The script above, works, I got my shipment, but I still have the `Ship` button:
[image]
I would expect that button to be no longer available, once I created a shipment.
Any idea what am I doing wrong ? with my script . Thank you

Comment: are you looking for a standalone script ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually,
I missed this part: `$shipment->getOrder()->save();`. By adding it , it fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
$shipment->register();

try{
     $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
         //Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface
         $this->shipmentRepositoryInterface->save($shipment);
    }catch (Exception $exception) {
        $this->logger->error(sprintf($exception->getMessage()))
    }
```

Comment: Thnx , but that still doesn't fix my issue. I still have the Ship button

Answer (score 0):

Just keep this script in your magento root directory and run after your store url also do not forget to replace you order id in the script

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$orderInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface');

//Use this if you have orderId
//$orderId = "100"; //Order Id
//$order = $orderInterface->load($orderId);

$incrementId = "000000165"; //Increment Id
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
        ->loadByAttribute('increment_id', $incrementId);

if ($order->canShip()) {
    // Initialize the order shipment object
    $convertOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
    $shipment = $convertOrder->toShipment($order);
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() AS $orderItem) {
        // Check if order item has qty to ship or is virtual
        if (! $orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
            continue;
        }
        $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
        // Create shipment item with qty
        $shipmentItem = $convertOrder->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
        // Add shipment item to shipment
        $shipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
    }

    // Register shipment
    $shipment->register();
    $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

    try {
        // Save created shipment and order
        $shipment->save();
        $shipment->getOrder()->save();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       echo "Shipment Not Created". $e->getMessage(); exit;
    }

    echo "Shipment Succesfully Generated for order: #".$incrementId;
} else {
    echo "Shipment Not Created Because It's already created or something went wrong";
}
```

hope this helps! thankss